# Is there any way to run Google Lighthouse with php + bash?

Tags: php, bash

I try to use [Google-Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) on my website.
I wrote a php file that called a bash-script to run lighthouse-cli.

**run_bash.php** :

```
  <?php

if(isset($_GET['subject2'])) {

$text = $_GET['subject2'];

$text = escapeshellarg($text);

$command = './rex.sh 2>&1 >> path/mylog ' . $text ;
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

}
?>
```

my bash script:

**rex.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
SITE=""
SITE=$1
VALUE=$(echo $SITE | awk -F'//' '{print $2}')
lighthouse $SITE --output html  --output-path ./path/$VALUE.html
```

and a simple php form that called `run_bash.php` well.

now problem is:
if I run my bash script in shell with Putty it works well but when call my URL and run `run_bash.php` these error show at browser:

```
    Sun, 05 Jun 2022 19:20:59 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...............................................................................................
Sun, 05 Jun 2022 19:21:00 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.................................................................................................
Sun, 05 Jun 2022 19:21:00 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...................................................................................................
Sun, 05 Jun 2022 19:21:01 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....................................................................................................
Sun, 05 Jun 2022 19:21:01 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......................................................................................................

Sun, 05 Jun 2022 19:21:01 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher:error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:33989
Sun, 05 Jun 2022 19:21:01 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher:error Logging contents of /tmp/lighthouse.dVx18OP/chrome-err.log

Unable to connect to Chrome
```

I'm curious to know if anyone has ever done this?
Or is it possible at all?

Comment: It's a configuration issue, what does the error log show? And is that the same user as with putty where it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **finally** found the answer!
I had to use function `exec()`in the php file to run the bash script as bellow.

```
$output = exec('./rex.sh  ' . $text  );
```

And another important point.
I changed the access level of all `/var/www/` path files to  `www-data`.